# JUnit Application Suite Testing

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to create a junit test suite that will run all of the test suites within the application... - this is what I have and as far as I can find it *should* work but it keeps telling me that no tests are found.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * @author Jason
 *
 */

@Test
public class applicationTest extends TestCase {

    public applicationTestSuite(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("ApplicationTestSuite");
        suite.addTest(domain.AllDomainTests.suite());
        suite.addTest(services.AllServicesTests.suite());
        suite.addTest(business.AllBusinessTests.suite());
        return suite;
    }
}
```

An example of one of the test suites it should be running -

```
package business;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ ItemMgrTest.class })
public class AllBusinessTests {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify Suite classes in your `@SuiteClasses`, for instance:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ AllBusinessTests.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

The suite() method is a JUnit 3 thing, and won't find any methods or tests in your suite, because you're using JUnit 4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark [`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) annotation on test method

**API Document**

> The Test annotation tells JUnit that the public void method to which it is attached can be run as a test case. To run the method, JUnit first constructs a fresh instance of the class then invokes the annotated method. Any exceptions thrown by the test will be reported by JUnit as a failure. If no exceptions are thrown, the test is assumed to have succeeded [[...]](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html)

Comment: The individual test suites run fine on their own... it is the aggregate test suite that is not working.